# "cryptography is required for sha256_password or caching_sha2_password"

Tags: python, mysql, cryptography, mysql-python

Good day. Hope your all are well. Can someone help me with fix this?

I'm new to the MySQL environment. I'm trying to connect to MySQL Database remotely. I used the following python code and got this error.

```
Print(e) = "cryptography is required for sha256_password or 
             caching_sha2_password"
```

And have no idea how to solve the error.

```
import pymysql as db

HOST = "XXXXX.XXX.XX”
PORT = XXXX
USER = "my_username"
PASSWORD = "my_password”
DB = "db_name"

try:
    connection = db.Connection(host=HOST, port=PORT,user=USER,                 
    passwd=PASSWORD, db=DB)

    dbhandler = connection.cursor()
    dbhandler.execute("SELECT * from table_name")
    result = dbhandler.fetchall()
    for item in result:
        print (DB)
 except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import mysql.connector
def connection():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "XXXXX",
                  user = 'XXXXX',
                  password = 'XXXXX',
                  database = 'login_page',
                  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

    c = conn.cursor()
    return c , conn
```

Download mysql connector rather than pymysql and try connecting this way. It worked for me, hope it works for u too.

Comment: Thank you, It work. I also needed to add the        
 "auth_plugin='mysql_native_password' " part into my code.

Answer (score 148):

The error message can be made more comprehensive and helpful. In order to fix this "cryptography" package needs to be installed.

```
pip install cryptography
```

Comment: Works perfectly with pymysql. Great work around on macOS where you may not prefer to install brew.

Comment: Any one getting RUST error on installing cryptography try upgrading pip

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly

Comment: if your are doing it using jupyter notebook, AFTER INSTALLING this package remember to RESTART your notebook

Answer (score 31):

To use “sha256_password” or “caching_sha2_password” for authenticate, you need to install additional dependency:

```
$ python3 -m pip install PyMySQL[rsa]
```

Source: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html

Comment: Thanks. Instead of just installing 'cryptography' as suggested in the accepted answer, doing this installs other dependencies (pycparser, cffi) in addition to cryptography.

Comment: FWIW, I think this is the correct answer. The documentation for the library in question identifies this as a requirement for using the sha* functions in question.

Answer (score 21):

For what it's worth, I had this problem today using MySQL via SQLAlchemy in Python. It turned out that I was using the wrong password for this account. In other words, if you have this problem, you might want to start by just confirming that you're using the correct password.

FWIW, I am not sure why this generated a cryptography message. Something buggy along the way?

Comment: ...and when you see that your password is correct make sure to use `"` instead of `'` to enclose the connect string. So instead of `SQLALCHEMY_DB_URL = 'mysql+pymysql://user:password@dbhost/mydb'` I used `SQLALCHEMY_DB_URL = "mysql+pymysql://user:password@dbhost/mydb"`. I guess its because of the special characters used in the string.

Answer (score 9):

*"This report means that sha256_password with caching_sha2_password These two encryption algorithms need to use cryptography.

Although the meaning is clear, you may not know how to solve it.

Actually, **cryptography** is a python package, so the solution is simple:"*

Try running `pip install cryptography` on you cmd or terminal.
Here is the [source](https://www.programmersought.com/article/28861270139/).

Answer (score 7):

I got the message because my database hadn't been started.

Comment: Thank you, I restarted my PC then I was getting this error. But I was pretty sure that this error is nothing do with `cryptography` package as mentioned in other answers. After reading your comment I restarted mysql service then it started working

Answer (score 6):

I also had this problem today using MySQL via SQLAlchemy in Python. It went away just by logging into the database via mysql -u root -p. Credit to @Ben for the hint. Something buggy may well be happening.

Comment: Instead of `root` I had to do the same with the user I was using in my script.

Comment: Also happened to me after restarting my machine and my Docker, I could not logging anymore. Restarting the MySQL container and re-logging into the database with that user (root in my case) solved the problem.

Comment: The trick worked for me. But after a server restart I had to do it again. So I rather decided to install the cryptography package to make server restarts more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

I met this problem too. When I try to solve the problem use method of @brcmipn in MySQL Worbench, it tells me MySQL is running in Super Safe Mode.So I use

```
SET GLOBAL READ_ONLY = OFF;
```

and after that the problem don't happen again.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to fix this RuntimeError, `pip install cryptography` is enough.

In my case, this error occurs when I use PyMySQL to connect MySQL 8.0 with wrong password. `caching_sha2_password` is MySQL 8.0 default authentication plugin. If the password is correct, error will not occur.

This explains Ben's doubt in his answer.

Because after first round authentication failed, PyMySQL tries to do full authentication with RSA. `sha2_rsa_encrypt` function relays on cryptography package.

https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/930b25034f1a3b6e3a202e072675f163770b25cb/pymysql/_auth.py#L209C43-L209C43

Even after installing cryptography, it raises `(1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'host' (using password: YES)")` error eventually if your password is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Easy on MYSQL Workbench. Create a new MySQL user and fill the "Limit to Host Matching" with your IP. Is % by default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading then upgrading PyMySQL worked for me.  This happened to me twice in the last few days, on Ubuntu 20 & 22.  I already had everything installed, and everything had been working the day before.  Here's what happened:

PyMySQL
1.0.2   - was working yesterday, failed today with crypto error

downgrade to
0.9     - works, no crypto error

upgrade back to
1.0.2    - works

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this today and the answer from @gajam is correct.

You can double check the database you are using and verify that the authentication type you are using (ie. MySQL server) for <user/root> is not set to "sha256_password” or “caching_sha2_password”. You can check via MySQL WorkBench > Users and Privileges.

If this is set and you are using pyMySQL to connect then you will have to install the RSA option (as commented by @gajam)

Note that I was also using SQLAlchemy when I stumbled upon this issue.

[image: PyMySQL Instructions]

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error:

**> "cryptography is required for sha256_password or

> caching_sha2_password"**
> I tried everything that came to my head and it did not work, the next day I just looked at my requirements.txt and discovered I have

*psycopg-binary==3.1.14
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9*

this only menans conflicts between these packages.
So I deleted the Virtual environment, deleted **psycopg2-binary==2.9.9** and created a new Virtual environment, then;

> pip install -r requirements.txt

Now everything is fine.
Gracias!!!

Comment: Psycopg is used for connecting to PostgreSQL, not MySQL.