# Can anyone solve the "Ultimate NOOB question on pymysql"?

Tags: python, pymysql

I'm just starting to play around with accessing mysql from python and chose to use pymysql.  I hit a wall immediately, though, when just testing making a connection to the database.  The code is simply...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='nunya', db='python')
```

When I run this code I get the following...

```
(base) [me@feynmann mysql]$ ./test-pymysql.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-pymysql.py", line 6, in <module>
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', 
password='nunya', db='python')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", 
line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 599, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 871, in 
_request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._process_auth(plugin_name, auth_packet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 900, in _process_auth
    return _auth.caching_sha2_password_auth(self, auth_packet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py", 
line 264, in caching_sha2_password_auth
    data = sha2_rsa_encrypt(conn.password, conn.salt, 
conn.server_public_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py", 
line 142, in sha2_rsa_encrypt
    raise RuntimeError("cryptography is required for sha256_password 
or caching_sha2_password")
RuntimeError: cryptography is required for sha256_password or 
 caching_sha2_password
```

I've done several searches, which mostly kept bringing me here, but nothing that seemed to make sense and/or fix the problem.

I also tries switching to the mysql.connector, but got similar but even more confusing errors.

I know this probably seems pretty stupid to most of you, but I'd appreciate any help you would offer.

Comment: Try 'pip install cryptography' maybe?

Comment: A search found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586797/1440565)

Comment: give this model a try. [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but cryptograpy was already installed.